# A Riemann integrable function $f$ on a bounded interval $[a, b]$ is measurable with respect to the Borel measure on $[a,b]$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow  [-\infty, \infty]$ is bounded and Riemann integrable, must it be measurable with respect to the Boreal measure on $[a,b]$?

Comment: A Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue integrable and hence it is Lebesgue measurable. I'm not sure about the fact that $f$ is Borel measurable. As you can see here, there are functions which are Lebesgue measurable, but not Borel measurable.

Comment: The above comment is false. $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: The above 2 comments are true in their respective contexts, which are not mentioned here. For a complete treatment, see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291020/does-riemann-integrable-imply-lebesgue-integrable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no. We know that a function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and a.e. continuous. So if you take $f$ to be the characteristic function of a non-Borel set contained in the standard $1/3$-Cantor set (these sets exist by axiom of choice and a neat construction), then $f$ is Riemann integrable but not Borel measurable. (It is Lebesgue-measurable, though.)

Comment: The existence of non-Borel subsets of the standard Cantor set doesn't require Choice, if I recall correctly. The cardinality of the Borel algebra is $\mathfrak c$ (see for example [this PDF](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m103f08/public_html/borel-sets-soln.pdf)) but there are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets of the standard Cantor set.

Comment: Oh, maybe that is an alternate proof. The one I know uses the existence of non-Lebesgue measurable sets and the invariance of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra under homeomorphisms.